# How to migrate data from Sqlite to Realm

Tags: android, sqlite, realm, android-sqlite, data-migration

I have data stored in sqlite DB and the application is in production. Now I am thinking to migrate data from Sqlite to Realm DB. I have a raw query to read data from Sqlite and while migration to realm inside migration class I am trying to store the data into realm but I am not succeeding. Can anyone help me in this.

```java
public class Test extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey
    private String name;
    private String sex; 
}



//Migration Class


@Override
protected void doMigration(final DynamicRealm dynamicRealm) {
    RealmSchema realmSchema = dynamicRealm.getSchema();

    if (!realmSchema.contains("Test")) {
        RealmObjectSchema testSchema = realmSchema.create("Test");
        testSchema.addField("name", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY);
        testSchema.addField("sex", String.class);


//Trying to migrate data store data to realm from sqlite during migration itself.

 testSchema.transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final DynamicRealmObject obj) {
        if (!sqlTest.isEmpty()) {  //data from Sqlite
            for (Test tempTest : sqlTest) { //looping for sqlite data
                obj.set("name", tempTest.getName();
                obj.set("sex", tempTest.getSex());
            }
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform method is used to mutate existing objects, like add column with default value, rename a column etc : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

When you have created your schema, you need to iterate your sql values and add data in realm, for example :

```java
for (SqlTest sqlData : sqlTest) {
    Test test1 = realm.createObject(Test.class, UUID.randomUUID());
    test1.setName(sqlData.getName());
    test1.setSex(sqlData.getSex());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Test tempTest : sqlTest) {    ##sqlTest is data from Sqlite##
     DynamicRealmObject realmObject = dynamicRealm.createObject("Test", 'PrimaryKey'); 
     realmObject.set("name", tempTest.getname()); 
     realmObject.set("sex", tempTest.getsex()); 
    }
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22510773)

Comment: @James Its not additional info its the complete answer which I used to solve my issue.

Comment: what James means is that you should add some explanation on _how_ this code works. That would improve your answer.

Comment: From the review queue this appears to be an edit to your original question. You need to provide more information to show that this is an answer and explain how and why it works.